# convert from intel syntax to at&t

Tags: assembly, g++, att

I'm trying to convert this code (ARM NEON) from intel to at&t syntax:

```
AREA    BRISK_ASM_NEON, CODE, READNOLY
    EXPORT  Function
    CODE32

Function    FUNCTION

loop
    pld     [r0, #192]
    vld2.32     {q8, q9}, [r0]!
    vld2.32     {q10, q11}, [r0]!
    pld     [r0, #192]
    vld2.32     {q12, q13}, [r0]!
    vld2.32     {q14, q15}, [r0]!

vcgt.u32    q8, q8, q9
vcgt.u32    q9, q10, q11
vcgt.u32    q10, q12, q13
vcgt.u32    q11, q14, q15

pld     [r0, #192]
vld2.32     {q12, q13}, [r0]!
vld2.32     {q14, q15}, [r0]!
pld     [r0, #192]
vld2.32     {q0, q1}, [r0]!
vld2.32     {q2, q3}, [r0]!

vcgt.u32    q12, q12, q13
vcgt.u32    q13, q14, q15
vcgt.u32    q14, q0, q1
vcgt.u32    q15, q2, q3

vsli.32     q8, q10, #8
vsli.32     q9, q11, #8
vsli.32     q8, q12, #16
vsli.32     q9, q13, #16
vsli.32     q8, q14, #24
vsli.32     q9, q15, #24

vsli.8      d16, d17, #2
vsli.8      d18, d19, #2
vsli.8      d16, d18, #4

vbic.i8     d16, #0xaa
vshr.u64    d17, d16, #31
vorr        d16, d16, d17

vst1.32     {d16[0]}, [r1]!

subs        r2, r2, #32
bgt     loop

bx  lr

ENDFUNC
END
```

I'm compiling with g++.
I found that this can be done when compiling by adding the directive *.intel_syntax*, but if I do that I obtain this message from the compiler:

```
Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.intel_syntax'.
```

I also tried to add -masm=intel when I compile but I get:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-masm=intel'
```

Do you know why I get this problems or could you give me a good reference I could use to translate from intel to at&t?
Thank you.

EDIT: I corrected it like this

```
.globl function

function:

loop:
    pld     [r0, #192]
    vld2.32     {q8, q9}, [r0]!
    vld2.32     {q10, q11}, [r0]!
    pld     [r0, #192]
    vld2.32     {q12, q13}, [r0]!
    vld2.32     {q14, q15}, [r0]!

    vcgt.u32    q8, q8, q9
    vcgt.u32    q9, q10, q11
    vcgt.u32    q10, q12, q13
    vcgt.u32    q11, q14, q15

    pld     [r0, #192]
    vld2.32     {q12, q13}, [r0]!
    vld2.32     {q14, q15}, [r0]!
    pld     [r0, #192]
    vld2.32     {q0, q1}, [r0]!
    vld2.32     {q2, q3}, [r0]!

    vcgt.u32    q12, q12, q13
    vcgt.u32    q13, q14, q15
    vcgt.u32    q14, q0, q1
    vcgt.u32    q15, q2, q3

    vsli.32     q8, q10, #8
    vsli.32     q9, q11, #8
    vsli.32     q8, q12, #16
    vsli.32     q9, q13, #16
    vsli.32     q8, q14, #24
    vsli.32     q9, q15, #24

    vsli.8      d16, d17, #2
    vsli.8      d18, d19, #2
    vsli.8      d16, d18, #4

    vbic.i8     d16, 10101010
    vshr.u64    d17, d16, #31
    vorr        d16, d16, d17

    vst1.32     {d16[0]}, [r1]!

    subs        r2, r2, #32
    bgt     loop

    bx  lr
```

Now it compiles fine except for this error:

```
Error: immediate value out of range -- `vbic.i8 d16,#0xaa'
```

Comment: Um, how is Intel or AT&T syntax relevant for ARM code? Wouldn't it make more sense to use ARM assembly syntax?

Comment: @Michael I'm using ARM assembly syntax. I thought I'd have to use AT&T in order to compile it with g++. Now it compiles fine except for the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Perhaps [the documentation for VBIC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHFBEDA.html) can offer a clue.

Comment: @user2696208 Michael is correct; the GNU assembler on ARM uses ... ARM's assembly syntax. The above will directly assemble. The "AT&T syntax" thing is a historical x86/i386 artifact that we [un]fortunately have to live with, but this issue never existed on any other hardware platform than x86.

Comment: Well, afaik it is a m68k artifact. AT&T is x86 assembler styled after m68k VAX syntax.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: VAX and m68k are quite different beasts :) but correct that AT&T syntax (and in fact the assembly syntax for many UN*X systems / CPUs used in UN*X systems) is strongly influenced by the VAX / PDP-11.